# VLOOKUP not finding values in Excel?

Tags: excel, vlookup

I know this must be something simple but I've read dozens of threads and I can't figure out my issue!

I'm trying to match species names from my list to a master species list to get the species code.  Originally, I had the data in a separate sheet but I combined it to the same sheet to see if that would fix my issue, but it didn't.

I know the VLOOKUP isn't working because I can see an exact match in the data.

Here is my formula: =VLOOKUP(B3,$G$1:$R$1233,1,FALSE)

I've also tried without the $, using just G:R but those didn't work either.

In this screenshot, you can see I'm looking for the species 'beech'.

[image]

The species text from B3 'beech' matches exactly to R1005 'beech', so why am I not getting a match?

[image]

One more screenshot, so you can see when I click out of D3 where the formula is, I get #N/A

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: With `VLOOKUP`, the key must be in the *leftmost* column of the lookup table. That is not the case with your data, so use `INDEX/MATCH`, or `XLOOKUP` if your version of Excel supports it.

Comment: thank you!  I moved column R to column F and changed the formula to =VLOOKUP(B3,F:G,2,FALSE) and it worked!